# scanf int8_t corrupts stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, scanf

How to scanf int8_t and other types without this error. I used "cinttypes" to get constants of patterns but that didn't help.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cinttypes>

int main()
{
    int8_t var;
    scanf("%" SCNi8, &var);
    printf("%" PRIi8 "\n", var);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. This error occures only in Debug, when building in Release it's OK.

P.P.S. Output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SCANF_PROBLEM, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  SCANF_PROBLEM.cpp
1>d:\study\scanf_problem\scanf_problem\scanf_problem.cpp(11): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          d:\visual studio\vc\include\stdio.h(283) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>  SCANF_PROBLEM.vcxproj -> D:\Study\SCANF_PROBLEM\Debug\SCANF_PROBLEM.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Why is the `SCNi8` outside of the quotes?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It's a character string literal. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.

Comment: David, I sow it that way in example using %hhi explicitly does not help.

Comment: @PeterSchneider  Thanks.  I've never run into a format string written quite that way. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It's a preprocessor constant representing the format specifier string for int8_t.

Comment: @KonstantinBerkow Which compiler and commands are you using to compile your code? What standard library are you linking against?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, I didn't do it manually. I am using VisualStudio13.

Comment: @KonstantinBerkow Well, if you can't compile and run by console then 1. What happens when your IDE breaks down and you can't use it any longer? and 2. How can you be expected to know how to configure your IDE to execute the correct commands?

Comment: It works fine on [ideone](https://ideone.com/u4so1S)

Comment: ... in spite of the fact that `printf("%"SCNi8"\n", var);` should be `printf("%"PRIi8"\n", var);`

Comment: @undefind behavior, it fails reaching }, printf not the problem.

Comment: This is C++, so `scanf` may well be the wrong answer anyway.  Include <iostream> and use `operator>>`; that will save you much `scanf`-related hair-pulling...

Comment: @nathanOliver, mhm, then it's some VS magic.

Comment: Are you sure this is your entire code? Because this should work just fine. Don't make us guess.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'd always argue the other way around: Use scanf/printf and avoid lots of iostream hair-pulling ;-).

Comment: @tenfour, yes it is. I think that line // SCANF_PROBLEM.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application. Won't affect code in any way.

Comment: I can confirm that with my copy of VS2013 I also get a stack coruption error around var using `scanf()` and `scanf_s()` in a debug build.  It works correctly in release build

Comment: Sounds like a VS bug then. Go figure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's blasphemy.  MS doesn't have compiler bugs :)#

Comment: I see that the format string SCNi8 in my VS 2013 is just "i" which indicates a normal integer. That the error is reported only in debug mode is probably just because of debug checking code. In relase mode the stack is corrupted as well, but no error is reported.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Good spot. That looks like an _answer_ to me...?

Comment: @PeterSchnider, I think this is some compiler stuff, I've used "%i", "%d", "%hhi", "%hhd", but all the same, maybe use OllyDebug to see if stack really corrupted.

Comment: You may be interested in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63417. mingw, iiuc, links against Microsoft's standard library and therefore runs into the same problem, apparently.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, so it's Windows problem, nice. This is answer.

Comment: We're talking about an implementation-defined feature which is yet to be documented as compliant. In terms of imp-def features, if it's not documented then it shouldn't exist and hence shouldn't be used. If you try to use something that isn't documented to exist/work, it's not a Windows problem; it's a you problem. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run into a bug of Microsoft's C/C++ runtime library, cf. http://mfctips.com/tag/format/ or https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63417 (which reports this bug for gcc under mingw, which links against the Microsft libs).

"%hhd" just doesn't work; you must program around it (which isn't too hard, but sad).

I am not aware of a bug report to MS (i.e., I did not see anything when I tried to google it).

Comment: I would appreciate detailed feedback, and I would paradoxically appreciate negative feedback most, for the sake of learning and for the sake of SO quality. (Currently I'm convinced the answer is correct and the MS bug described in it is the reason for the OP's trouble.)

Answer (score 2):

Even in C99, those extended integer types aren't required to exist, unless the documentation says they exist, more on that later... Even if those extended integer types do exist they're not required to have `scanf` format specifiers. See [n1256 section 7.8.1p6](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#7.8.1p6) for this quote:

> For each type that the implementation provides in `<stdint.h>`, the corresponding
>   `fprintf` macros shall be defined and the corresponding `fscanf` macros shall be
>   defined unless the implementation does not have a suitable `fscanf` length modifier for
>   the type.

As for C++, well... C++11 delegates that `<cstdint>` shall essentially be a wrapper for C99s `<stdint.h>`, and the functions it refers to be wrappers for the C99 equivalents.

Here's the kicker: Microsoft has never cared all that much about C99, to the extent that [they're willing to document "N/A" for extended integer support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#c99table), for example.

Make sure your compiler is configured to compile as C99 or later, or C++11 or later, and link to a C99-or-later-compliant standard library. `SCNi8` may exist in the headers, but if `scanf` doesn't support it (which it won't, prior to C99/C++11 compliance) then you won't have any luck with it... and of course, *make sure your standard library documents support for the implementation-defined features you intend to use*.

Protip: If your filename ends in .c, Microsoft Visual Studio will attempt to compile your code as C89. That's probably not going to be helpful. MSVC++'s C99-compliance in terms of the standard library isn't too great even when you tell it to compile as C++11. You should probably learn how to determine which compiler/library versions you're using... while you're learning how to compile using the command line.

Protip #2: You can use [LLVM/Clang in Visual Studio](https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx). Make sure you link to a C99-compliant standard library (e.g. not Microsoft).

Protip #3: You might want to change `SCNi8` for `PRIi8` when using `printf`...

Protip #4: See [footnote 191](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#7.8.1p1) for this quote:

> C++ implementations should define these macros only when `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` is defined
>   before `<inttypes.h>` is included.